# Import content manager components in Strapi custom plugin

Tags: strapi

I’m building a Strapi plugin and I'm trying to reuse some of the componentes from content-manager in the admin directory in the plugin files like this:

```
import NonRepeatableComponent from "@strapi/admin/admin/src/content-manager/components/NonRepeatableComponent";
```

But I’m getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@strapi/admin/admin/src/content-manager/components/NonRepeatableComponent/index.js 22:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (22:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

Is there any webpack config I have to add to make it work?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution here?